# Accepting an input of multiple formats

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a code that accepts a date, however I want to give the user the ability to enter the date as dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy. My code is below, I tried to use OR but it does not work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main ()
{
    int dayA, monthA, yearA,

    printf("First date in format DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d" || "%d-%d-%d", &dayA, monthA, yearA);
```

Comment: You are taking input in wrong way, please read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm, and in your case it will be better to use string for input.

Comment: It will be better if explain how you are going to use this date.

Comment: I'm creating a code that reads two dates and calculates the difference in days between, however I'm comfortable with that part. once I learn how to accept the date in both formats I can do the same for the second date

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it. It inputs into a string, and then checks if one of the format methods works. It's always essential to check the return value from the `scanf` function family, to know if the conversion succeeded.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int dayA, monthA, yearA;
    puts("Enter a date dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy");
    char datestr[32];
    if(fgets(datestr, sizeof datestr, stdin) != NULL) {
        if(sscanf(datestr, "%d/%d/%d", &dayA, &monthA, &yearA) == 3 ||    // added missing &
           sscanf(datestr, "%d-%d-%d", &dayA, &monthA, &yearA) == 3) {
              printf("Date is day %d, month %d, year %d\n", dayA, monthA, yearA);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are two runs of the program:

```
Enter a date dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy
23/4/2020
Date is day 23, month 4, year 2020
```

Enter a date dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy
23-4-2020
Date is day 23, month 4, year 2020